# Where did "Open with" (user defined command) go?

Tags: nautilus

I'm now using Ubuntu 12.04.

In earlier versions you could associate a filetype with a specific command (e.g. self-compiled binary) by selecting "Open with" in the file's properties and select the command by providing the file path manually if it wasn't already in the list of applications.

Is this possibility gone?

The only way I found now is to create .desktop files and edit the mimetypes via an text editor.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for an answer like this. A user has asked for help on how to open `fits` file type that is not supported by default ubuntu programs.

[IraGainesUK](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=787718) has posted the answer at http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12242314&postcount=5

> I also can't believe it me took this long to figure out how to do such
>   a simple thing in 12.04(!!), but the simple way is this:
>
> 1) Install Ubuntu Tweak:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
> ```
>
> 2) Open it up on the command line:
>
> ```
> $ ubuntu-tweak
> ```
>
> 3) Navigate to `Admins` > `File Type Manager` and click `All`. This may
>   take a moment whilst it scans all your mimetypes.
>
> 4) Uncheck `Only show filetypes with associated applications` at the
>   bottom (again, may take some time).
>
> 5) Click anywhere in the right-hand panel and start typing `fits` to
>   begin searching for the `FITS document` mimetype. Hopefully you should
>   find it.
>
> 6) Double click it, and click `Add` and then your custom command (for
>   me, topcat, for you, ds9).

I should note that I have tested the solution and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on any file and go to properties you'll find a dialog option to set the default application for opening such files.

Comment: But "Add" is greyed out...

Comment: Actually, "Add" just moves where in the list the already-known programs are, so this answer doesn't answer the question.  We want to know what happened to custom-defined commands.